# Image in TabWidget pushing text off the screen. How to make button bigger to fit image and text?

Tags: android

I have a tab widget that's appearing like follows. I need to use large images, like the image on the right, but when I do it pushes the text off the bottom of the screen. How can I get the tab button to grow 'up' rather than down?

[image]

This is the layout for the TabWidget:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/tabScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="0">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is the layout of the tab button:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_host_default_height"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/TabAppTheme"

    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        style="@style/TabTextAppTheme" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the style (modifying `minHeight` doesn't do anything):

```
<style name="TabAppTheme">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_holo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">120dip</item>
  <item name="android:minHeight">120dip</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextAppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">180dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to modify the tab height here:

```
<resources>
    <!--<dimen name="tab_host_default_height">48dp</dimen>-->
  <dimen name="tab_host_default_height">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```